# can't get my web site, on IIS, to work with URL beginning with www

Tags: windows, iis, asp.net, azure

I added my vb.net web app to IIS 8 on my Azure Windows 2012 server R2 VM. Then, I did IIS > right-click Sites > Add Web Site and set "Site name" to my_site.org and set Physical path to project directory for my web site and set "Host name" also to my_site.org.

Works great. From Internet, I browse to http://my_site.org and it runs OK.

Now I want people to also browse to www.my_site.org but when I Add Web Site, just like above, but for www.my_site.org it adds ok, but when I select www.my_site.org and click IIS Browse www.my_site.org browser pops up but reads "webpage cannot be found" Nor can I browse it from Internet.

Comment: Did you create its DNS entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in your dns a cname record with www towards your my_domain.org